# "Неверный хэш MD5" при установке

Tags: linux, bash, md5, calendar, install

Стояла задача поставить [Apple iCal](https://github.com/apple/ccs-calendarserver). Всё по инструкции - git, ./bin/develop. Далее доходим до момента:

```
No cache file: /home/client/ccs-calendarserver/.develop/pkg/CyrusSASL-7d31e058298aa97ca0c040b5df09fcd1-cyrus-sasl-2.1.26.tar.gz
Downloading CyrusSASL...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:02:09 --:--:--     0
curl: (28) Failed to connect to ftp.cyrusimap.org port 21: Connection timed out
```

[На GitHub проекта выяснил](https://github.com/apple/ccs-calendarserver/issues/545), что данный FTP уже не доступен, и надо заменить ссылку. Иду, как сказано, в bin/_build.sh, нахожу объект с этим самым Cyrus:

```
  ruler;
  if find_header sasl.h; then
    using_system "SASL";
  elif find_header sasl/sasl.h; then
    if "${do_setup}"; then
      mkdir -p "${c_glue_include}";
      echo "#include <sasl/sasl.h>" > "${c_glue_include}/sasl.h"
      using_system "SASL";
    fi;
  else
    local v="2.1.26";
    local n="cyrus-sasl";
    local p="${n}-${v}";

    c_dependency -m "a7f4e5e559a0e37b3ffc438c9456e425" \
      "CyrusSASL" "${p}" \
      "ftp://ftp.cyrusimap.org/cyrus-sasl/${p}.tar.gz" \
      --disable-macos-framework;
  fi;
```

Меняю `ftp://ftp.cyrusimap.org/cyrus-sasl/${p}.tar.gz` на `https://www.cyrusimap.org/releases/${p}.tar.gz`, в ответ получаю:

```
ERROR: MD5 sum for downloaded file is wrong: bb44d26003a2b044e235aae2fc8427f7 != a7f4e5e559a0e37b3ffc438c9456e425
```

Пробую в bin/_build.sh заменять строку после `c_dependency -m` на ту, что требуется (`bb44d...`):

```
Checking MD5 sum for CyrusSASL...
SHA1 sum for CyrusSASL is 766d5f2eda5b1461dce4fc5b59eb0802150ee2cb
Unpacking CyrusSASL from cache...
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Я так понял, что если меняется файл, то и его MD5-хэш тоже. [На GitHub](https://github.com/apple/ccs-calendarserver/issues/545) написано что-то похожее на хэш, но он неполный - `83eba6ba8..0e3204c8d`

Также напрягает тот факт, что по `https://www.cyrusimap.org/releases/cyrus-sasl-2.1.26.tar.gz` ничего нет, так что отойдём от варианта скачать оттуда.

У меня есть уже готовый .tar.gz, подсунуть прямо в папку и указать локальный путь не вышло - установщик ждёт ссылки. На файлообменник сбросить и скачать, разумеется, не удалось, FTP поднять тоже не смог (по крайней мере, с него не получалось скачивать).

Как мне в итоге подсунуть файл инсталлятору (или указать локальный путь как Web-адрес)?

Заранее спасибо!

P. S. Не кидайтесь пожалуйста тапками, ибо занимаюсь таким не так часто :3

Comment: Нет, то, что вы видите как хеш, это куски из дерева Git. Вам оно не надо. У вас вместо файла с правильным архивом скачивается скорее всего HTML 404.  Проверьте. Так что и новый линк уже не работающий.  Вам нужно https://github.com/cyrusimap/cyrus-sasl/releases/download/cyrus-sasl-2.1.26/cyrus-sasl-2.1.26.tar.gz (хеш тот же)

Comment: @0andriy То есть просто вставить эту ссылку вместо всех тех?